# Appending Pythonpath, importing modules from different directories on windows

Tags: python, windows, import, python-3.4, pythonpath

I have been working with Learn Python The Hard Way and I'm stuck at example 48. In example 47 I had to create directories that look like this:

```
skeleton
|--ex47
   |--module.py
   |--__init__.py
|--tests
   |--ex47_tests.py
   |--__init__.py
```

From now on I had to import ex47/module.py into tests/ex47_tests.py. I received the 'No module named ex47' error. The solution for this problem was to add path of ex47 directory to site-packages by adding two lines of code into module.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./ex47')
```

And this worked fine. I could import module.py to ex47_tests.py and I can import it anywhere on my computer.

After moving to example 48 I created exactly the same directories, files, I added path to ex48/ and I keep receiving the `'No module named 48'`. I searched internet for different solutions, none of them is working. Adding `__init__.py` into skeleton doesn't help.

This issue is super basic matter, however it is not introduced to new python programmers. 
By the way, I want a solution that would work on any computer that would work with my code.

Do such issues occur in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to see is where from, you are invoking the python program.
I have the following files.

```
C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop>tree /f skeleton
Folder PATH listing for volume ????
Volume serial number is 6AE1-4919
C:\USERS\KUMARVIVEK\DESKTOP\SKELETON
│   __init__.py
│
├───ex47
│       mod.py
│       mod.pyc
│       __init__.py
│       __init__.pyc
│
└───tests
        ex47_tests.py
        __init__.py


C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop>
```

With the following contents:

```
C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop>type skeleton\ex47\mod.py
import os
x = "C:\\Users\\kumarvivek\\Desktop\\skeleton\\ex47\\module.py"
directoryPath= os.path.dirname(x)
fileName = os.path.basename(x)
print "\nFilePath:      %s\nDirectoryPath: %s\nFileName:      %s\n" %(x, directo
ryPath, fileName)
C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop>
```

And

```
import sys

# If the Current Working directory is skeleton
# C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop\skeleton>python C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop\skeleton\tests\ex47_tests.py
#
# sys.path.append(r"..\skeleton")

# If the Current Working directory is any of these "tests" or "ex47"
# C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop\skeleton\tests>python C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop\skeleton\tests\ex47_tests.py
# C:\Users\kumarvivek\Desktop\skeleton\ex47>
#
# sys.path.append(r"..\..\skeleton")

sys.path.append(r"..\..\skeleton")


from ex47 import mod

print mod.x , mod.directoryPath, mod.fileName
```